# Create rows without looping SQL

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to create rows without using looping functions?

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable(id int)
DECLARE @i int = 0
DECLARE @numrows int = 5
WHILE @i<@numrows
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #tempTable VALUES(@i)
SET @i = @i+1
END
SELECT * FROM #tempTable
```

Can I get the same result without looping. I'm using SQL Server 2014

Comment: I would say the following series is tailor made for you:

 - [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1), [part 2](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2), and  [part 3](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as taken from here https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

```
SELECT TOP (5) n = CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]))
INTO #tempTable
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2

SELECT *
FROM #tempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use a [numbers](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) table

```
INSERT INTO #tempTable 
select number from numbers where number<=5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of [`Tally table`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) which can be created like below

```
DECLARE @numrows int = 5

select 
 top (select @numrows)
 row_number() over( order by (select 1)) id
from
sys.objects s1 cross join
sys.objects s2
```

Note that we are not using anything from s1 or s1 in the query SELECT

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/WIN52000)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Another option that doesn't involves reading data from an arbitrary table is to use a "function of numbers" to generate artificial rows that can further be turned into feeding other tables. Something like this will do:

```sql
WITH
L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A, L0 AS B),
L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A, L1 AS B),
L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A, L2 AS B),
L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A, L3 AS B),
L5   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A, L4 AS B),
Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c) AS n FROM L5)
INSERT INTO #tempTable (id)
SELECT n FROM Nums WHERE n <= @numrows
```

Originally taken from here: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#fn_nums